# WPF ancestor binding

Tags: c#, wpf

What am I doing wrong to get this error?

```
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSome.Views"

 <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button" Command="{Binding CloseInstanceCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CFDOpenPositionsView}}}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29.709" Margin="359.292,0,0,0" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle4}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="66.728" Background="#FFDDDDDD" Visibility="Visible"/>

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CloseInstanceCommand' property not found on 'object' ''CFDOpenPositionsView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:
Path=CloseInstanceCommand; DataItem='CFDOpenPositionsView' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Class CFDOpenPositionView has CloseInstanceCommand property...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RelativeSource binding will return a UI Element. You need to specify that the property is on the DataContext object:

```
<Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button" Command="{Binding DataContext.CloseInstanceCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:CFDOpenPositionsView}}}"
```